# Progress Bar using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a progress bar in my page using JQuery. If i hardcoded the value as 10 means, in the progressbar " 10% Completed " should be displayed. How to do this..Please guide me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var val = 10;
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: val
});

<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, how to reduce the height and width of the progress bar

Answer (score 0):

may be this discussion help you...

[progress bar using jquery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-progress-bar-with-javascript/)

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, how to reduce the height and width of the progress bar.